# Error Dao class must be annotated with @Dao

Tags: java, android, android-room

I used the following code to use in the Room Library library

```
public interface DataTable extends Dao {

    @Insert
    long add(Model model);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM tbl_room")
    List<Model> getItem();

    @Update
    int update(Model model);

    @Delete
    int deleteItem(Model model);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM tbl_room WHERE name LIKE '%' || :key || '%'")
    List<Model> search(String key);

    @Query("DELETE FROM tbl_room")
    void deleteAll();

}
```

And the following error is given:

error: Dao class must be annotated with @Dao
public interface DataTable extends Dao {

Comment: `Dao class must be annotated with @Dao` The error can't be more descriptive than that.. Precede/annotate the `DataTable` with @Dao

Answer (score 0):

**DAO** should be Annotated like this.

```
@Dao    
public interface DataTable{

@Insert
long add(Model model);

@Query("SELECT * FROM tbl_room")
List<Model> getItem();

@Update
int update(Model model);

@Delete
int deleteItem(Model model);

@Query("SELECT * FROM tbl_room WHERE name LIKE '%' || :key || '%'")
List<Model> search(String key);

@Query("DELETE FROM tbl_room")
void deleteAll();
```

}